# Permission denied at ExternalStorageDirectory access via Flutter plugin

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I wrote an plugin to access the ExternalStorageDirectory on Android via Dart.

android specific code for the plugin:

```
@Override
  public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
    if (call.method.equals("getUserDataDirectory")) {
      String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
      result.success(path);
    } else {
      result.notImplemented();
    }
  }
```

The returned path is correct `storage/emulated/0`. But now if i try to iterate throw the directory i get an Permission denied.

error.log

```
[ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 3381): FileSystemException: Directory listing failed, path = '/storage/emulated/0/' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
E/flutter ( 3381): #0      _Directory._fillWithDirectoryListing (dart:io-patch/directory_patch.dart:32)
E/flutter ( 3381): #1      _Directory.listSync (directory_impl.dart:214)
E/flutter ( 3381): #2      _MyAppState.initPathRequest (/data/user/0/com.yourcompany.userdatadirectoryexample/cache/exampleIAKNFP/example/lib/main.dart:34:25)
```

main.dart

```
  path = await Userdatadirectory.getUserDataDirectory;

    var dir = new Directory(path);

    List contents = dir.listSync();
    for (var fileOrDir in contents) {
      print(fileOrDir.path);
    }
```

my `example/android/app/src/AndroidManifest.xml` contains these additional premissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Check for Runtime Permission. Refer https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162638/grant-permission-required-for-external-storage-in-android-m

Comment: Ok but now i have te problem that i cant acces the Activity so i cant call requestPermission(). So is it possible to get the Context or Activity in an Flutter plugin project? And how?

Comment: I am trying to access /storage/emulated/ directory but getting error "Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Directory listing failed, path = '/storage/emulated/' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)" while i have granted WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. Any suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

it'll happen if you're on Android Q | 10.

And it will be solved by adding the following on the manifest file.

```
<application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Comment: Tthis is the exact answer i want. Thanks much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63364476/requestlegacyexternalstorage-is-not-working-in-android-11-api-30

Answer (score 3):

use [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
```

before download action you need check storage permission:

```
var status = await Permission.storage.status;
if (!status.isGranted) {
   await Permission.storage.request();
}
```

hope to help some body

Comment: What happens if the user says no? Is there an "exit app if says no" option?

Comment: This is work but also needed another answer, like setting on androidManifest.xml

Answer (score 2):

You can use either of these 2 package to ask for device permission: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/simple_permissions or https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/permission . They have simple APIs and comprehensive examples.

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/permission is good enough for me. thx

Answer (score 1):

Add the following on AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Also make these changes in android\app\build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 29

targetSdkVersion 29
```

It will work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63364476/requestlegacyexternalstorage-is-not-working-in-android-11-api-30