# How to deal with requestLegacyExternalStorage and WRITE/READ permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, permissions

I read the documentation and also searched for a potential solution. However, it's still not clear how to deal with. In my project, I used these permission lines in the app's `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to give corresponding accesses. Also, I handle those permissions in `onRequestPermissionsResult()` to ensure that the user allows them. However, recently I go this warinig

```
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE no longer provides write access when targeting Android 10, unless you use requestLegacyExternalStorage
```

My app supports Android versions 21+ and seemly Android 10 and above versions do not require above mentioned permissions.

How can I deal with the `requestLegacyExternalStorage` and `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE />`
to keep functionable for all supported Android versions (21 and above)?

Comment: "and seemly Android 10 and above versions do not require above mentioned permissions" - this is untrue and based on use case : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage.  The documentation is a bit of a mess with pockets of information in different places as the permissions and storage models have changed.  This is related to this question and answers : https://stackoverflow.com/q/63364476/4252352