# Black Screen after taking photo in image_picker plugin

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I am using latest version of `image_picker`plugin, including Flutter 2.0.3 version and also this is failing on a real device(Xiaomi Redmi Note 7).The only message I can see is Lost connection to device when I take the camera. Gallery works fine.This is my code.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  File _image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Image Picker Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _image == null
            ? Text('No image selected.')
            : Image.file(_image),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: getImage,
        tooltip: 'Pick Image',
        child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I already added all permissions.How can solve this problem?

Comment: could you provide the logs

Comment: @JiteshMohite As I said only message I can see is Lost connection to device. If you meant Logcat How can I provide infinite messages here

Comment: if you are runing android device, then see android logcats, you will get something there

Comment: `2021-03-30 17:00:29.900 29803-29803/com.example.flutter_app_image_save E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict"
2021-03-30 17:00:29.966 29803-29861/com.example.flutter_app_image_save E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.example.flutter_app_image_save
2021-03-30 17:00:29.966 29803-29861/com.example.flutter_app_image_save E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array` @JiteshMohite there were errors like this when I try to take a photo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the menifest `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
// ....
        defaultConfig {
            targetSdkVersion 29
```

This should work for you, if want to know more about then click [`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63364476/requestlegacyexternalstorage-is-not-working-in-android-11-api-30)

Comment: I changed it compileSdkVersion from 30 to 29 and it worked

Comment: have you used android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ?

Comment: Yes I have. I used it when installing image_picker plugin