# Android mkdirs() return false on Android 11 with Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Tags: android, storage, android-sdcard, mkdirs

Mkdirs() function is not working on Android 11. every thing is working fine on Android 10 and lower.

Code:

```
***String path =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/My_directory/";
    File temp_file = new File(path);
    if (!temp_file.exists()){
        Boolean can_create= temp_file.mkdir();
    }***
```

the above code returns true in case of Android 10 or lower. but returns false in case of Android 11.
Manifest permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Noting that runtime permission is considered for same (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and  WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).

Manifest application:

```
    <application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

The only way I am able to write in external storage  is using `getExternalFilesDir()` but this is not the root directory.

according to this [developer](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) website,  we can't create folders any more in the root directory!

Questions so far after checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58379655/2828651):

1- Is it confirmed that in Android 11 we can't create any folder on the root directory? any work around?

2-If yes, what is the way forward to save data in external storage, excluding `getExternalFilesDir()` ?

3- Why `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` is not working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [requestLegacyExternalStorage is not working in Android 11 - API 30](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63364476/requestlegacyexternalstorage-is-not-working-in-android-11-api-30)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` is not working?

`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage` is no longer works on Android 11+. It is just a helper on Android 10 to give developers more time before migrating to scoped storage. On scoped storage, you need to use URI for creating, renaming, moving files, etc. Thus `java.io.File` is almost useless now.

> Is it confirmed that in Android 11 we can't create any folder on the root directory? any workaround?

No workaround.

BTW, to reduce scoped storage complexity, I've created a library named [Simple Storage](https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage). It works across API levels.

Comment: Can you point to a documentation where they say that the support for java.io.File will be removed in the future and that using the URI will be made mandatory? As per my understanding, google tried this, but it bounced back and now they will continue to provide support for file APIs. That is the reason in Android 11, you dont even need the flag to request support for Java APIs.

Comment: @Roadblock It will not be removed in the future, but its limitation makes it almost useless. You can read this post: https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html

Answer (score 11):

> ***String path =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/My_directory/";

You cannot create directories in root of external storage on Android 11 devices.

Instead create your own directories in one of the public directories of external storage.

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "My_directory");
```

Comment: No need to use public directory, already mentioned that getExternalFilesDir() is working.

Comment: Interesting didn't know this, saved it. Atleast I will spend less time on debugging this in the future if I ever do run across it