# Android; Downloaded file not shown in android while using getExternalFilesDir;

Tags: java, android, file, sdk, android-download-manager

I updated Android SDK TO 30 Then Issues occurred while downloading the pdf file from api.

> At SDK 29
> `Uri uri1 = Uri.fromFile(newFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), ""));`

Above code was working fine. After upgrading to SDK 30 following code doesn't show the downloaded file.

> My Code

````
        File direct2 = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null)+ FileUtils.DOWNLOAD_PDF_DESTINAION);

        if (!direct2.exists()) {
            direct2.mkdirs();
        }

        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            Uri uri1 = Uri.fromFile(new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), ""));
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                    .setAllowedOverRoaming(true).setTitle(title + strDate + ".pdf")
                    .setDescription(description)
                    .setDestinationUri(uri1)
                    .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);//to show the DOWNLOAD notification when completed
        } ```
````

Comment: Can you confirm is you are using scoped storage or is requestLegacyExternalStorage=true  is this added in your AndroidManifest.xml file. 
If above key is added it won't work as this has been deprecated in api 30 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63364476/requestlegacyexternalstorage-is-not-working-in-android-11-api-30)

Comment: I have added requestLegacyExternalStorage= true in manifest and it was still not working. Do I need to use both Scoped storage and requestLegacyExternalStorage or any one?

Comment: If you update sdk 30 ,  requestLegacyExternalStorage won't work in android 10 and 11. You have to upgrade to scope storage. 
 requestLegacyExternalStorage= true  , only works for sdk 29

Comment: I tried to use scope storage. File is created but its size was 0B. I need to download PDF file from Server. How can I use it?

Comment: You can try looking at how file download works in android 11 [link](https://github.com/jignesh8992/Android-11-Permissiond-And-Download-Manager) 
If you still faces the issue, please update the code so that we can look for the issue together